# Batch file to send files through ip

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

im new with .bat files.
Im trying to create a .bat file that backups files from a PC to a server PC that is not in the same network.
In this case, i can connect to the server pc with my home pc with remote desktop (got the IP, domani username and password), and i want to make a batch file that sends files from my house pc, to the server pc in my job.
Is there any type of way to send them? 
This is what i tried so far:

PROGRAM 1:

```
copy C:\FROM_HERE \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\C:\TO_HERE
net use \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\C:\TO_HERE /user:username password
robocopy \xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\C:\TO_HERE C:\FROM_HERE
net use /delete
pause
```

This program says that the route cannot be found. 
I dont know, any suggestion please?

Comment: just to be clear, in CMD if i ping this IP, the sent packeges are recived, but i if go to the address bar of the explorer and type \\THE_IP, it wont connect since its not in the same network

Comment: Any updates to your question should be made by modifying your post.

Comment: yeah. That just isn't going to work.  Using remote desktop is one thing but file sharing is another.  You have to configure firewall settings and security settings.  Trust me, you don't want to do this insecurely over the Internet.  If you want to share files with your work computer I suggest using something like DropBox.  Although this was a utility I used years ago to transfer files over Terminal Services.  It may still work. http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/System/tsdc/Freeware.htm

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have downloaded it, could you explain me a little bit how to use it?